# Change of icon using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to change the list icon. Once the list icon is clicked then a list will open and the icon should change the icon to close icon. again on click on close it should change to list icon.

Here is the code what I have tried:
HTML:

```
<div id="menuLayout">
    <a href="#menuLayout" id="openMenuLayout">
        <img src='http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/visualpharm/icons8-metro-style/32/Timeline-List-Grid-List-icon.png' />
        <img src="http://seotobiz.com/images/icon_close.png" style='display:none;'/></a>
    <nav id="menuLayoutList">
      <ul>
        <li>
            <form id="search">
              <input type="search" placeholder="Search...">
            </form>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#homeLayout">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#aboutLayout">About Us</a></li>
        <li><a href="#KeyLayout">Key Facts</a></li>
        <li><a href="#teamLayout">Team</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Register</a></li>
        <li><a href="#contactLayout">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
```

Jquery:

```
$("#openMenuLayout").click(function(e){
      debugger;
            if ($('#menuLayout').hasClass('open-menu')){
          $('#menuLayout').removeClass('open-menu');
                $('#openMenuLayout').find('img').removeClass().addClass('opened_icon');

                $(this).css('display','block');
        } else {
          $('#menuLayout').addClass('open-menu');
                $('#openMenuLayout').find('img').removeClass().addClass('open-menu_icon');
                 $(this).css('display','block');
        }

        e.preventDefault();
 });
```

Css:

```
#menuLayout {
display: block;
position: fixed;
width: 280px;
height: 100%;
z-index: 99;
top: 0;
left: -280px;
box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
transition: left 0.2s ease-in-out;
-ms-transition: left 0.2s ease-in-out;
-o-transition: left 0.2s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition: left 0.2s ease-in-out;
-webkit-transition: left 0.2s ease-in-out;
-webkit-perspective: 1000;
-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
-webkit-transform: translate(0px, 0px);
background-color: #b11c1c;
background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(center top , #b11c1c, #AD3335);
background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 100%, from(#b11c1c), to(#AD3335));
background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #b11c1c, #6A0001);
background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #b11c1c, #6A0001);
background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #b11c1c, #6A0001);
background-repeat: repeat-x;
filter: progid:dximagetransform.microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#ffb11c1c', endColorstr='#ffAD3335', GradientType=0);
filter: progid:dximagetransform.microsoft.gradient(enabled=false);
}

#openMenuLayout {
position: absolute;
background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
width: 32px;
height: 32px;
font-size: 16px;
color: #FFF;
line-height: 32px;
text-align: left;
z-index: 999;
top: 20px;
right: -52px;
text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
-webkit-border-radius: 2px;
-moz-border-radius: 2px;
border-radius: 2px;
}

img {
max-width: 100%;
}

#menuLayout.open-menu {
left: 0;
}

#menuLayout.open-menu #openMenuLayout {
left: 20px;
right: auto;
}
nav#menuLayoutList {
position: relative;
margin: 70px 0;
}

nav#menuLayoutList ul {
position: relative;
margin: 0;
}
```

[New Link](http://jsfiddle.net/WDqZ2/1/)

Comment: What does the open-menu_icon class do ? Well, what all those classes do ?

Answer (score 2):

What you want to achieve is not that hard.

I suggest you to use div elements instead of image elements and, use the css property `background-image` to define it.

This enables you to use two seperate css classes (with different background images), one for the opened menu and one for the closed one.

Further, it is now possible to use [css sprites](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_image_sprites.asp) to avoid image flickering due not loaded resources and to avoid multiple http requests.

Your implementation should look similar to this. Just replace `background-color` with `background-image`. If you deploy your application remember that you can avoid image flickering with the sprite technique.

http://jsfiddle.net/V5vg9/

Comment: And that's exactly something we should never suggest without saying: "Use the Sprite technique" or at least "Preload first your icon images!" :) The OP is doing it already well, cause the browser loaded both images at first.

Comment: I know that, I wasn't finished writing the answer and, only images with display:hidden are preloaded ;)

Comment: `display:hidden;` doesn't exist in CSS. You might edit your answer to add some more info, it would be awesome

Comment: Sorry, display: none does preload images. Looks like I mixed two different things together.

Answer (score 0):

I think you search [toggleClass](https://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/):

```
$("#openMenuLayout").click(function(e){
    $(this).toggleClass('close');
}
```

then define in CSS a `open` class and a `close` class with the open and close `background-image`.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use hide and show functions? is ver most simple

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
<div id="menuLayout">
    <a href="#menuLayout" id="openMenuLayout">
        <img class="list" src='http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/visualpharm/icons8-metro-style/32/Timeline-List-Grid-List-icon.png' style='display:none;' />
        <img class="close" src="http://seotobiz.com/images/icon_close.png" /></a>
    <nav id="menuLayoutList">
      <ul>
        <li>
            <form id="search">
              <input type="search" placeholder="Search...">
            </form>
        </li>
        <li><a class="a" href="javascript:;" id="home">Home</a></li>
        <li><a class="a" href="javascript:;" id="aboutLayout">About Us</a></li>
        <li><a class="a" href="javascript:;" id="KeyLayout">Key Facts</a></li>
        <li><a class="a" href="javascript:;" id="teamLayout">Team</a></li>
        <li><a class="a" href="javascript:;" id="#">Register</a></li>
        <li><a class="a" href="javascript:;" id="contactLayout">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $('.a').click(function(){
    if($(this).hasClass("v")){
        $('.list').hide();
        $('.close').show();
        $(this).toggleClass("v");
    }else{
        $('.list').show();
        $('.close').hide();
        $(this).toggleClass("v");
    }

 });

</script>
```

Now, u need detect with $(this).attr("id"); for anchor